# Replace innerHTML if string like 'price 0 &euro;'

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to replace the innerHTML of a span id="price" using jQuery. I think I'm doing it wrong with the RegExp.

```
$(function(){

    var element = $('#price');
    var contenu = element.innerHTML;
    var str = " 0 ";
    var re = new RegExp("^.*"+str+".*","gi"); 

    if (contenu.match(re)){    
        element.innerHTML="free";
    }
});
```

It returns nothing when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to change the content of the element if it contains the string `" 0 "`, then you may simply do

```
$(function(){
    $('#price:contains(" 0 ")').html('free');
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/egEQExe/1/edit)

If you want to change it only if " 0 " is the whole content, do this :

```
$(function(){
    if ($('#price').text().trim()==="0") $('#price').text('free');
});
```

Comment: It looks more simple, indeed. The problem is the element not only contains " 0 " but other text before and after 0.

Comment: See edit if you want to change the text only if doesn't contain anything else.

Comment: Your solution works, but it doesn't work on my site. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the string rendered in #price is a PHP value.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var element = $('#price');
```

will give you back a jQuery array, not the DOM element. It doesn't have properties like `innerHTML`. You need to get the actual DOM element.

Try this before you continue:

```
var element = $('#price')[0];
```

Or, rework your code to work with jQuery results:

```
$(function(){

    var element = $('#price');
    var contenu = element.html();
    var str = " 0 ";
    var re = new RegExp("^.*"+str+".*","gi"); 

    if (contenu.match(re)){    
        element.html("free");
    }
});
```

I can't say for sure whether your regular expression is correct.  You haven't given a concrete sample input of your span content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
$(function(){
  var element = $('#price');
  var contenu = element.html();
  var str = " 0 ";
  var re = new RegExp("^.*"+str+".*","gi"); 

  if (contenu.match(re)){    
    element.html("free");
  }
});
```

jQuery doesn't return a simple DOM element.  Rather it returns an array of every DO element that matched you selector wrapped in a jQuery wrapper so can't simply use DOM properties like innerHTML.  If you want the first element that matches the selector '#price' as a raw DOM element then you could use `$('#price')[0]`  and then `$('#price')[0].innerHTML` will work as expected.  Alternately you can embrace the jQuery philosophy and use `$('#price').html()` to get the value or `$('#price').html(value)` to set the value.